# Kafka outbound channel can't take message from a channel

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-kafka

There is a channel :

```
<integration:channel id="sampleChannel">
</integration:channel>
```

And there is a kafka outbound channel with sampleChannel value for channel property :

```
  <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter"
                                        kafka-template="template"
                                        auto-startup="false"
                                        channel="sampleChannel"
                                        topic="foo"
                                        sync="false"
                                        send-failure-channel="errorChannel"
                                        partition-id-expression="1">
    </int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

When message sends and get to sampleChannel, this exception throws :

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1623b78d.sampleChannel'
```

Why kafka outbound can't take message from the sampleChannel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `auto-startup` is set to *false*, so at the time when Application Context is started there is no subscriber to the `sampleChannel`. 
Set `auto-startup` to *true*. Or change your `sampleChannel` to be pollable of publish-subscribe channel.

Comment: I wonder if we should add more info into that `Dispatcher has no subscribers` message. For example really say `"Perhaps a subscriber is not autoStartup."`

Comment: Thanks it worked. Had to spend almost a day to get around this issue